# Redirect every page no matter how deeply nested to a single page on same domain

Tags: apache, redirect

I've seen several answers to this, but none of them seem to work on subdirectories or nested URLs.

Basically, I want to redirect *everything* on a domain, no matter whether specified with a direct URL or a directory, no matter how deeply nested, to a "site closed" or "maintenance" page, on the same domain.

For example, all of these:

```
example.com
example.com/page.html
example.com/sub
example.com/sub/page.html
example.com/sub/sub2
example.com/sub/sub2/page.html
```

...should redirect to `https://example.com/index_closed.html`

I can get it to work on example.com, but not nested directories.

Also, it should NOT redirect .css files, if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/index_closed.html [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on nested URLs. It works on example.com/page.html. It does not work on something like example.com/sub/page.html.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index_closed.html$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteRule $ /index_closed.html [R=302,L]
```